# Find the number that follows the rules of two different series

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

I have this logic problem where I need to find a number that fits in 2 different series (vertical and horizontal). Each series has a rule, and once you find them, you can determine the answer.

$$
        \begin{matrix}
          &  & 546 &  &  \\
          &  & 228 &  &  \\
         758 & 246 & ? & 625 & 319 \\
          &  & 476 &  &  \\
          &  & 109 &  &  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Answers: A) 337 B) 143 C) 532 D) 125 E) 931

The horizontal series' rule seems to be that the middle digit follows a linear sequence, which means that the number we're looking for has a middle digit of 3. This means A), C), or E).

I have have tried many different things to find the vertical rule (factoring, multiplying digits, adding digits, searching for sequences), but I cannot, for the life of me, discover what it is.

Any help?

**Edit (spoiler)**:

> If it can help anyone reverse engineer the rule, the answer is 931, but it hasn't helped me finding it...

Comment: This is likely not the rule, but of the five choices, the correct one from "spoiler" is the only one which does not cause there to be three or more of any digit in either the across sequence or the down sequence. [That allows one to use only digits $1,3,7,8,9$ so any of $5*4*3=60$ numbers could be in the middle, however only one of these is listed among the choices.]

Comment: Clearly neither the row rule nor the column rule can uniquely determine the  number. So these rules could be "fuzzy" or negative rules such as every number in the column being different in every digit from any other number in the column (not the case here).